# Convertir un arreglo de objetos a un sólo objeto

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de JS. Tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos:

```
let arr = [{ "nombre": "jhon" }, { "cargo": "developer" }]
```

En donde el resultado esperado sería un solo objeto que contengan los elementos del arreglo:

```
let result = {"nombre": "jhon", "cargo": "developer"};
```

Intenté hacerlo con `map()`, pero lo que obtengo son 2 objetos separados por cada elemento del arreglo, y lo que necesito es tener solo *un objeto* donde estén los elementos del arreglo:

```js
let obj = [{ "nombre": "jhon" }, { "cargo": "developer" }];
Object.values(obj).map(e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

En ECMAScript 2018+ puedes usar la [sintaxis Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) combinada con [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Por ejemplo:

```js
let arr = [{ "nombre": "jhon" }, { "cargo": "developer" }]

const merged=(Object.assign({}, ...arr));
console.log(merged);
```

En ECMA Script 2015 puedes usar [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) combinada con `reduce()`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let arr = [{ "nombre": "jhon" }, { "cargo": "developer" }]

const merged=arr.reduce(((r, c) => Object.assign(r, c)), {});
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar `Object.assign` para unir los objetos en uno solo.
El primer argumento es el objeto destino, y los siguientes son los objetos a unir.

```
const arr = [{ "nombre": "jhon" }, { "cargo": "developer" }]
const result = Object.assign({}, ...arr);

console.log(result); // { nombre: 'jhon', cargo: 'developer' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Algo más sencillo, puedes hacerlo utilizando solamente el método [**`Object.assign()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
let arr = [{ "nombre": "jhon" }, { "cargo": "developer" }]
let result = {};

result = Object.assign(arr[0], arr[1])

console.log(result);
```